# Django form returning blank to next template

Tags: python, django, forms

My form seems to never be returning the input from one template to the other and I am having a hard time understanding why.

forms.py:

```
class textForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import textForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# The nbar statement is used to show which one is active


def index(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/home.html')

def article(Request):
    if Request.method == 'POST':
        form = textForm(Request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            form = textForm()
            context = {'message': message, 'form': form}
            #if request is valid and post, send info to next template
            return render(Request, 'index/article.html', context)
    else:
        form = textForm()
    #else return to the template where user fills out input
    return render(Request, 'index/translate.html', {'form': form})


def translate(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/translate.html', {'nbar': 'translate'})

def most_popular(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/most_popular.html', {'nbar': 'most_popular'})

def the_news(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/news.html', {'nbar': 'news'})

def sports(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/sports.html', {'nbar': 'sports'})

def science(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/science.html', {'nbar': 'science'})

def politics(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/politics.html', {'nbar': 'politics'})

def funny(Request):
    return render (Request, 'index/funny.html', {'nbar': 'funny'})
```

index/translate.html where the form is, where the user inputs the text:

```
{% extends "index/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
   <h5 style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 40px;"><strong>welcome!</strong></h5>

   <form action="/article" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form  }}
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

index/article.html where I'd like to return the value from the form:

```
{% extends "index/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!-- the first div functionality will be created later -->
<div>
    <h2 style="font-size:45px; margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: -15px;"> article title </h2>
</div>

<div class="card border border-dark" style = "padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -10px; margin-left: -10px;">
        <p class="card-title"><strong> result:</strong> </p>
        <p class="card-text">  {{ message }} </p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The result I am getting is that {{message}} in the second HTML file is always blank - it does not return anything

Comment: Why you add `<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" required />` to your form? It's not needed! It already provide by `{{form}}`.

Comment: who suggested to you to make variable name as capital latter

Comment: Rename `textForm` to `TextForm` first letter should be capital. And rename `Request` to `request`. It will not solve your problem, but it good style.

Comment: I don't understand what these two template files are. You render the same template, article.html, in both cases. So what is the second file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman its to return the user to the input page in case theres no input and/or is incorrect

Comment: That didn't answer the question at all. Which one is article.html? What is the other one? Where is the code that renders it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in your template. It should be:

```
<form action="/article" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And edit your view like this:

```
def article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            form = TextForm()
            context = {'message': message, 'form': form}
            return render(request, 'index/article.html', context)
    else:
        form = TextForm()
    return render(request, 'index/article.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: thanks a lot! however I don't have any form being rendered on my template just the "submit" button

Comment: @kirkosaur add to question full template code and views.py.

Comment: added, I also just wanted to take the time to thank you so much for helping me, im a noob and I am having a really hard time figuring this out. I noticed the form field and result do work when I write make a get request to go to index/article.html. But not when I go to index.translate.html (the first template) thats where I'd like it to be to then return the result to article.html

Comment: I GOT IT BY MYSELF!! thank you so much for everything again!!